# Add to Cart API in Magento

Tags: php, api, magento, e-commerce

I need to know how can I add products into cart using API. I have a list of products with details, I am trying to call the API from outside Magento. In which Magento's core class implements this function??

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: can you please share your solution ? I am also looking for it. Thank you.

Comment: @SachinVairagi Please check the accepted answer. It was a long time ago and I am not remembering more on it.

Comment: actually I need more source code , thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

magento uses MVC and by looking at the cart link you can extract the path to the module, however

```
 Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction()
```

is the method you are looking for , remember that it is depending on session

Answer (score 0):

In order to add to the cart you're going to have to implement your own API.  That can be difficult because as Anton mentioned, it depends on session.

There was a project out there at one time, [Mammoth Web Services](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/PHP+%28UK%29/extension/1730/mammoth_webservices-0-3-0-tgz), by some guys in the UK, but the project has gone silent.

Answer (score 0):

If you have magento id's for your products this is fairly simple

http://yoursite.com/index.php/checkout/cart/add?product=product_id&qty=qty

Comment: No I want to write an API to add items to cart and remove items from cart.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/release_notes#Release%20Notes%20-%20Magento%201.4.2.0%20%28December%208,%202010%29

included in 1.4.2.0 apparently, though not on the official API documentation yet